# Python: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, mysql, django

here i am getting the error,

```
 File "C:\Users\DEEDEVTR01\Desktop\python\pyenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py",
 line 84, in Connect
 return Connection(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DEEDEVTR01\Desktop\python\pyenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py",
 line 179, in __init__
 super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2) TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I think the connection is proper but I am not sure why I am getting this error, it would be great if anyone can help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'NAME': 'deebaco',
        'USER': 'deebaco',
        'PASSWORD': 'deebaco',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


import MySQLdb

def connection():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(database="deebaco", user = "deebaco", password = "deebaco", host = "localhost", port = "3306")

    print ("Opened database connect successfully")

    cur = conn.cursor()

    return cur, conn
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.views import APIView

import MySQLdb
from testpro.settings import connection
cur, conn = connection()

class Product_ListAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        cur,conn = connection()
        query = ''' SELECT * FROM products'''
        try:
            with conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
                cursor.execute(query)
                result = cursor.fetchall()
                data = list(result)

            return Response({"data":result},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

I think the connection is proper but I am not sure why I am getting this error, it would be great if anyone can help me figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: Are you working on Debian Linux?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the port of the connection have quotes?

If so, remove the quotes in order to solve this issue:

from:

```
port = "3306"
```

to

```
port = 3306
```

Comment: now i am getting the AssertionError,    Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

Comment: in the exception handling part, add after `print` return Response(status=status. HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

Comment: can you please explain me where i am getting the error? it's look like internal server error.